# JSF 2.0 on a J2EE 1.4 compliant Application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, application-server, websphere-6.1

Can I use a JSF 2.0 implemntation on a J2ee 1.4 server ( jboss 4.0.5 / 5.0 , Weblogic 9, WebSphere 6.1 )?

Are there any (free) implementation that runs well on all platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible, because JSF 2.0 requires version 2.5 of the Servlet API, and J2EE 1.4 only supports Servlet 2.4. However, it is possible that a given concrete J2EE 1.4 implementation may support Servlet 2.5 anyway (but lack other components of Java EE 5).

I'm using Apache MyFaces and have no complaints, however I am not using it cross-platform. But I wouldn't expect issues in that regard; JSF is really just a framework built on top of the Servlet API and doesn't do anything remotely platform-specific.

Comment: Can youtell me what version of MyFaces are you using on what Application server?

Comment: @Sammyrulez: I'm using MyFaces 2.0.2 on Tomcat 7.